# Unable to create basic database or scale from web database in azure

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database

When attempting to either create a new basic database or upgrade from the web database to a basic database I get an error - "The operation is not supported for your subscription offer type."

I recently upgraded from the free trial to the pay-as-you-go option and the current database is in the North Europe location.

I have checked the preview features section but the ability to enable the premium database options are not there and I believe these are no longer in preview mode anyway.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: this is a billing issue, open a billing support ticket. Billing tickets are free and included in your subscription.

Comment: Thank you. I will attempt this now.

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I am also facing the same issue. @agentJIM